# Meteor 1.0: Upsert with Mongo Selector

Tags: meteor

I am trying to do an upsert on the server side with a custom field as the unique identifier instead of a mongo id (data is being pulled from a 3rd party api).

A simplified version of what I am trying to achieve:

```
var myItem = {
    myUniqueID : 'abc123',
    name: 'foo'
};

MyCollection.upsert(
    {
        "myUniqueID ": myItem.myUniqueID
    },
    {
        "$set": myItem
    }
);
```

I receive the following error:
Error: Meteor does not currently support objects other than ObjectID as ids

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this was caused by me adding:

```
MyCollection._ensureIndex({myUniqueID : 1}, {unique: 1});
```

right after declaring the Mongo Collection... even when I commented this line out the damage had been done.. I had to rename the collection (essentially create a new collection) to get past it.